# How to derive the following equation in quantum mechanics？

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

How to derive the following equation in quantum mechanics？

$$u\cdot\nabla\psi=-\frac{\hbar}{2m}i\Delta\psi-\frac{1}{2}(\nabla\cdot u)\psi+\frac{\hbar}{4m\rho}\left(2|\nabla\psi|^{2}i\psi-\frac{\psi}{\rho}\nabla\rho\cdot\nabla s+\psi\Delta s\right)$$

where

$$u\equiv\frac{\boldsymbol{J}}{\boldsymbol{\rho}}=\frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{\nabla\overline{\psi}i\psi-\overline{\psi}i\nabla\psi}{\overline{\psi}\psi},s\equiv\bar{\psi}i\psi $$

This is the derivation of equation (S10) in an article, and the address of the article is: https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.00596

I am a beginner.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What I want to ask is how to derive from the left side of the equation to the right side of the equation. I don't know the detailed process of derivation

Comment: You have failed to show the reader what you get by substituting the suitable expressions on the left and right hand sides, differentiating by parts, and comparing them to each other.